# Difficulties when using dynamic form in React, with useFieldArray from react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm making a registration screen, where there is a dynamic form, using react-hook-form's useFieldArray. In this form there are some fields, for example, two selects: One to choose the state and the other to choose the city. When selecting the state of the first select, a search in the api will be carried out, listing all the cities of the selected state and this will feed the second select with these cities. However, for that I am using a useState that, when changed, the cities of the select will be changed as well. The problem is that as it is a dynamic form, when I perform an append(), adding a new field of this form, the city of one ends up changing the city of the other.
Below I will show in pictures what happens:

[Here, it is possible to notice that, when the state Minas Gerais was selected, a search was made to an api, which returned all the cities of Minas Gerais, filling in the select city. After that, Alfenas was selected by the user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STZmy.png)

[Here, I clicked on Add person responsible, and an append() was performed on the dynamic form, that is, these two selects of State and city that are appearing, are a "copy" of those above. I selected another state, in this case the Federal District and the list of cities was updated, allowing Brasília to be selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAojq.png)

[Now, back to the first field of this dynamic form, it is possible to observe that the previously selected municipality, Alfenas, is no longer there, since the list of municipalities no longer has the value Alfenas, since the state of the other field has changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6xKW.png)

I would like each field of this dynamic form to be independent of each other, whenever I need a useState to control some action I end up with the same problem... I would like to know what alternative to work around this situation.

Here is a snippet of non-functional code, just to show how my application is handling the dynamic form, the most important part here is the part of useState listaMunicipios, which is what is causing the problem I mentioned earlier:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import { OpcaoProps, Select } from "./Select/Select";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
 
export default function App() {
  const { control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { responsaveis: [{}] },
    mode: "onChange",
  });
 
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "responsaveis",
  });
 
  const apiEstados =
    "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados?orderBy=nome";
 
  const listarEstados = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(apiEstados);
    return response.data;
  };
 
  const apiMunicipios =
    "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/";
 
  const listarMunicipios = async (uf) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${apiMunicipios}${uf}/municipios`);
    return response.data;
  };
 
  const [listaMunicipios, setListaMunicipios] = useState([]);
  const [listaEstados, setListaEstados] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setListaEstados(listarEstados);
  }, []);
 
  return fields.map((field, index) => {
    <div className="App">
      <label className="inputLabel">Estado*</label>
      <Select
        opcoes={listaEstados.map((uf) => {
          return {
           label: uf.nome,
           value: uf.id,
          } as OpcaoProps;
        })}
        placeholder="Selecione um estado..."
        selecione
        onChange={async (e) => {
          const listaDeMunicipios = await listarMunicipios(e.target.value);
          setListaMunicipios(listaDeMunicipios);
        }}
      />
      <label className="inputLabel">Município*</label>
      <Select
        opcoes={listaMunicipios.map((municipio) => {
          return {
            label: municipio.nome,
            value: municipio.id,
          } as OpcaoProps;
        })}
        placeholder="Selecione um município..."
        selecione
      />
      <Button
        label="Adicionar Responsável"
        onClick={() => {
          append({ nome: "" });
        }}
      />
    </div>;
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.